# fgets dont return NULL when no new line found

Tags: c, crash, new-operator, line, fgets

well i'm using while loop:

> while(fgets(pclientRow, 1024 , f) != NULL)

in other classes it works ok, but in one of them, when i'm reading from
file line by line, it won't get out of the loop even when the lines end, i saw that in the debugger.

why is it? and it was working even in that class before and now i dont know why it keep bringing
empty lines untill it's crshing..

any idea?

Comment: Post some code. Also note that C does not have classes.

Comment: What are the values of `feof(f)`, `ferror(f)`, and `errno` (Unix) / `GetLastError()` (Windows) in the state where the file should have ended but fgets is not returning NULL?

Comment: It would also be useful to know how large the file being read is (both in bytes and in lines) and exactly what happens when it "crashes".

Comment: sorry the fgets isn't crashing, it entering the loop again because fgets didnt return null and then it' crashing afcourse..

Comment: @Zack: fgets() is a standard library function, so even in Windows it sets errno.

Comment: fgets() returns NULL on either error, or end-of-file, if that is not happening for you, there is something else wrong, probably in code you have not posted.  Post a complete example. I would guess that you have overrun a buffer or overflowed the stack or similar, but without the code, that is just a guess.  Note also that NULL is a macro subject to erroneous definition, use `!= 0` instead to be sure.

Comment: @Kobby: I meant, it would be good to know how the *program* crashes (it seems like it should just go into an infinite loop).  @Clifford: If this were Windows I would want to know the raw GetLastError code anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fgets in a standard ANSI C function, see documentation:
Here fgets read max. 1023 character up to next '\n' or EOF.
Your lines are longer than 1023 character or the last line has no terminating newline.

Answer (score 0):

You could catch the \n issue by placing something like this in your while loop.

if((int)strlen(pclientRow) == 1)
  break;